# How to create a Instagram like drop down alert?

Tags: swift, instagram, alert

I want to customize the code of a third party libary to show a Instagram like drop down alert below the UINavigationBar. 
The third libary i would like to customize: https://github.com/trilliwon/JDropDownAlert

At the end it should look somehow similar to this:
https://i.postimg.cc/nhqGB1CC/IMG-2792.png

I do not know how to move it down under the NavBar and appreciate any help you give me.

*Sry for my bad English*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [NotificationBanner](https://github.com/Daltron/NotificationBanner) Library instead of "JDropDownAlert".
This library does the thing that you want.
The library you mentioned is no longer supported.

Comment: Its a nice library but it is not working to display the alert under the UINavigationBar although they say: By default, each banner will be displayed on the main application window. If you are wanting to show a banner below a navigation bar, simply show on the view controller that is within the navigation system:

banner.show(on: viewController) ---- I used banner.show(on: self) but it is not working.